# Dragging, dropping and horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an jQuery browser based game where I use jQuery drag and drop (UL list).
How can I also let the user horizontally scroll this list with swipe of the mouse?

**UPDATE**

I am using this code. I do not want to show all cards in the first row at once. The user should be able to horizontally scroll among them. http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: I am using this code. I do not want to show all cards in the first row at once. The user should be able to horizontally scroll among them. http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop your own solution, take a look at the jQuery documentation regarding [`.scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/).